# postgres: Build select query using the cross tab or any json functions

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, crosstab, postgresql-12

```
create table foo (i int, j text);

select table_schema, table_name, column_name , ordinal_position 
from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'foo';

Output

table_schema   table_name  column_name  ordinal_position
public         foo             i             1 
public         foo             j             2
```

By using second statement I need to form a select query `select i, j from public.foo`. A simple function would suffice where if we pass a table name the result can be the string of select statement

Comment: The solution will be simple once the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select concat_ws(' ',
    'select',
    string_agg(column_name, ', ' order by ordinal_position),
    'from',
    table_schema || '.' || table_name
) q
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'foo'
group by table_schema, table_name
```

Or without a `group by` clause:

```
select concat_ws(' ',
    'select',
    string_agg(column_name, ', ' order by ordinal_position),
    'from',
    max(table_schema) || '.' || max(table_name)
) q
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'foo' and table_schema = 'public'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=425fd3db18906a2131e3c8017f9fec92)**:

```
| q                           |
| :-------------------------- |
| select i, j from public.foo |
```